# Required Field Validation Server Side

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, telerik, requiredfieldvalidator

I am planning to fire the required filed validation in my button click event.

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator10"  runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="RadDatePicker3" OnLoad="RequiredFieldValidator10_Load"
    Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>


 protected void RequiredFieldValidator10_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            if (RadDatePicker4.DbSelectedDate == null || RadDatePicker3.DbSelectedDate == null)
            {
                RequiredFieldValidator10.ErrorMessage = "*";
                RequiredFieldValidator11.ErrorMessage = "*";
            }
        }
    }
```

On my button click I wnat to check the required field validation...any suggestions??

The above code is not working for me.

Comment: Use `CustomValidator` with `OnServerValidate` event and set `.IsValid` to `True` or `false` after you check values and this will automatically display error message.

Answer (score 3):

You should just be able to call the following in the button click event

```
RequiredFieldValidator10.Validate();
RequiredFieldValidator10.IsValid;
```

The first method triggers the validator, the second gets the result.

Comment: Yes they do, the raddatepicker extended all it's validation properties for the requiredfieldvalidator. For example.  If the date isn't in the range set in the raddatepicker, the requiredfieldvalidator will be triggered.

Here's a demo from the telerik website that uses the validator

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/calendar/examples/datepicker/validation/defaultcs.aspx

Comment: I am not able to call RequiredFieldValidator10.IsValid; method in button click....throws error..do i need any namespace??

Answer (score 0):

When you are using validators against custom controls, you need to specify the validationproperty attribute to indicate the property which will contain the value of the control.One way in this case would be of extending the radcontrol and in that class implement a property to which the validationproperty attribute will point at. The property needs to take its value from the base class. 
P.s. Please let me know if more details or a sample is required.